# how to show image only when it is completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an img tag on my web page. I give it the url for an IP camera from where it get images and display them. I want to show image when it is completely loaded. so that I can avoid flickering. I do the following.

```
<img id="stream"
  width="1280" height="720" 
  alt="Press reload if no video displays" 
  border="0" style="cursor:crosshair; border:medium; border:thick" />

<button type="button" id="btnStartLive" onclick="onStartLiveBtnClick()">Start Live</button>
```

javascript code

```
function LoadImage()
{
  x = document.getElementById("stream");    
  x.src = "http://IP:PORT/jpg/image.jpg" + "?" + escape(new Date());
}

function onStartLiveBtnClick()
{       
  intervalID = setInterval(LoadImage, 0);
}
```

in this code. when image is large. it takes some time to load. in the mean time it start showing the part of image loaded. I want to display full image and skip the loading part Thanks

Comment: Do NOT set an interval for loading the image and then add a date to the url of the image. It will load the image again and again and again and again and... Also do not set the interval to zero, but set it to at least 100ms to make it run more smooth.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Preload the image and replace the source of the `<img />` after the image has finished loading.

```
function LoadImage() {
    var img = new Image(),
        x = document.getElementById("stream");

    img.onload = function() {
        x.src = img.src;
    };

    img.src = "http://IP:PORT/jpg/image.jpg" + "?_=" + (+new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following appears to work fine for me

```html
 <img src="/path/to/image.png" 
    class="d-none" 
    onload="this.classList.remove('d-none')"
 >
```

Basically I hide the `img` element and show it only after the image is loaded. Here `d-none` is the bootstrap class that defines `display:none` but you can define your own class if you are not using bootstrap.

If you would like to reserve the space for the image even adding a default background, you can use a wrapper `div` with `ratio ratio-4x3` (for bootstrap) or its equivalance CSS (e.g. padding a `wrapper` with `height=0` in proportion to width), and set a background to `img` through css.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `complete` property to check if the image has finished loading. However, I think there are other issues with your code, mainly you are repeatedly loading the same image. Instead, you should load it only once and then check the `complete` property in an interval.

Something like this should work:

```
function LoadImage()
{
  x = document.getElementById("stream");    
  x.src = "http://IP:PORT/jpg/image.jpg" + "?" + escape(new Date());
  x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function CheckIsLoaded() {
  x = document.getElementById("stream");    
  if (x.complete) x.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function onStartLiveBtnClick()
{       
  LoadImage();
  intervalID = setInterval(CheckIsLoaded, 0);
}
```